# communication between pipe using popen

Tags: c, file-io

i want to :

1. optimize this code eventually by using fgetc and feof.
2. know if there is another do what this code do

The basic idea of ​​my code is to create a counter that increments with each call to popen. As soon as the counter reaches a certain value, in this case 5, it communicates to all the processes before its state and then closes

```
    int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
        
        int counter = atoi(argv[1]);
    
        if (counter == 5) {
            printf("I am number 5, I Quit !\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
            return 0;
        }
    
        char new_command [20];
        snprintf(new_command, sizeof(new_command), "%s %d", argv[0], counter+1);
        FILE* fp = popen(new_command, "r");
    
        const struct timespec chock = {0,10000};
    
        char letter;
        char keep_on = 'y';
        while(keep_on == 'y') {
            while(fread(&letter, sizeof(letter), 1, fp) != 0) {
                printf("%c", letter);
                if (letter == '\n') {
                    keep_on = 'n';
                }
    
            }
            fflush(stdout);
            nanosleep(&chock, NULL);
        }
    
        printf("%d: Finished\n", counter);

    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question, exactly? I think you should read some of this: [ask] and clarify your question (button "edit")

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int` value which will be the value of the character or the special value `EOF`. So you can change `char letter;` to `int letter;` and change `while(fread(&letter, sizeof(letter), 1, fp) != 0)` to `while((letter=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)` if you want to use `fgetc` instead of `fread`.

Comment: @lan Abbott I did what you said but it gives me an infinite loop